# Finding indices of duplicate items in Python

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, duplicates, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy-ndarray with the following size: `(416,2)` i.e.

`[[10,10],[3,6],[2,4],[10,10],[0,0],[2,4],...]` etc

I need to find if there are any duplicates, and if so, where they are. The value of the duplicates itself does not matter (i.e. the above example would make: `[0,2,3,5,...]` )

Is there any way do achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: @bzoei Can you elaborate, how exactly do you need to find the dupes because as far the given array the dupes will be at positions `[0, 3, 4..]`?

Comment: @Shubham also thought the same, but looks like author needed indices of non-unique items, not items with duplicated values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have a numpy array, you can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and use the `return_inverse` flag. Use the inverse array to find all positions where count of unique elements exceeds 1, and find their indices.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[10,10],[3,6],[2,4],[10,10],[0,0],[2,4]])
vals, inverse, count = np.unique(arr,
                                 return_inverse=True,
                                 return_counts=True,
                                 axis=0)
out = np.where(count[inverse] > 1)[0] #find all indices where counts > 1
print(out) #array([0, 2, 3, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @bzoei The accepted solution take `O(n^2)` time. I think this is better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Correct, this will scale linearly with time `O(n)`, so bigger arrays should see bigger gains. edit: also, not sure why the downvote. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the numpy array to a list

```
items = [[10,10],[3,6],[2,4],[10,10],[0,0],[2,4]]
index = [i for i, v in enumerate(items) if items.count(v) > 1]
```

`index` will be `[0, 2, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [3, 4]])
temp = []
tempdict = {}
i = 0
for array in a:
    try:
        tempdict[str(array)].append(i)
    except:
        tempdict[str(array)] = [i]
    i += 1
for key in tempdict:
    if len(tempdict[key]) > 1:
        print(tempdict[key])
```

This will return the indexes of the numpy array where there are duplicates, and does not require conversion to a regular python list.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to keep everything in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

narray = np.array([[10,10],[3,6],[2,4],[10,10],[0,0],[2,4]])
u, c = np.unique(narray, return_counts=True, axis = 0)
dup = u[c > 1]
array_indices = np.unique(np.nonzero(np.isin(narray, dup))[0])
```